# How to install Firebase/auth in Vue js

Tags: git, firebase, vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I am working on Vuetify. I wanna add firebase authentication
command:

```
npm install --save firebase firebase/app firebase/auth firebase/database
```

I got this error

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/firebase/database.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I already added SSH into my Github. It works well until now
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I also first tried installing firebase/auth, @firebase/auth, none of them worked. I then installed only firebase with the command, as the answer above.

```
npm install --save firebase
```

In the main.js I had to add a configuration to initialize firebase.

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "yourkey",
    // authDomain: "configure if needed",
    // projectId: "configure if needed",
    // storageBucket: "configure if needed",
    // messagingSenderId: "configure if needed",
    // appId: "configure if needed"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do `npm install --save firebase`.

Then in your `firebaseConfig.js` file, you would do:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/auth';
//...
```

More details in the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) (Tab "Using module bundlers") and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#libraries-bundle) (expand the "Available Firebase JS SDKs (using bundler with modules)" category).

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I have no firebaseConfig.js. Where can  I create and configure it?

Comment: Have a look at this [Github repo](https://github.com/savvyapps/SAVuegram/tree/master/src) for example. Also look at how Firebase is imported in the components: `const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')`.